# (Python) Type Error: 'function' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

Hi I have the block of code here

```
def name_emoji(s):
    return(s in emoji.is_emoji['en'])

assert(name_emoji("❤️"))
assert(not name_emoji(":-)"))
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong but I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [34], in <cell line: 4>()
      1 def name_emoji(s):
      2     return(s in emoji.is_emoji['en'])
----> 4 assert(name_emoji("❤️"))
      5 assert(not name_emoji(":-)"))

Input In [34], in name_emoji(s)
      1 def name_emoji(s):
----> 2     return(s in emoji.is_emoji['en'])

TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: `emoji.is_emoji` is a function, not a dictionary. You want parenthesis instead of square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

The error "*something* is not subscriptable" points out that you are trying to access data using the indexing operator `[]` on some object which is not array like. In your case, `emoji.is_emoji` is actually a function.
Maybe you intended to call the function and use indexing on the result, which looks like

```
emoji.is_emoji()['en']`
```

Or maybe you only need to pass the `'en'` string as a parameter, which looks like:

```
emoji.is_emoji('en')
```

Comment: When I pass the 'en' string as a parameter I get:
```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [42], in <cell line: 4>()
      1 def name_emoji(s):
      2     return(s in emoji.is_emoji('en'))
----> 4 assert(name_emoji("❤️"))
      5 assert(not name_emoji(":-)"))

Input In [42], in name_emoji(s)
      1 def name_emoji(s):
----> 2     return(s in emoji.is_emoji('en'))
```

Comment: Instead of trying to guess the parameters and its return values I suggest to read its documentation.